# Gulp run and finish tasks then exit, not running gulp.dest()

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have the snippet below that runs my tasks:

```
gulp.task('default', ['js', 'css', 'test'], function() {
  process.exit();
});
```

When not using the `process.exit();` line it works, and I see the `app-xxxxxx.js` in my build folder.  Here's an abbreviated version of my js task (logic remains the same in the others but has a different responsibility):

```
gulp.task('js', function(cb) {
  var scripts = ['script1.js', 'etcetc.js'];

  var g = gulp.src(javascripts)
              .pipe(concat('app-xxxxx.js'))
              .pipe(gulp.dest('public/build')); //the file isn't in public/build

  setTimeout(cb, 100);

  return g;
});
```

My goal is to make sure all of my tasks finish, and when they do finish properly, exit gulp.  What's the problem with the snippets above?

Comment: Gulp will probably think the task finished as soon as the stream `g` finished. I guess you don't want to return `g`.

Comment: Didn't work when I wasn't returning g

Comment: What exactly "didn't work"? Accepting a callback should suffice: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#async-task-support . Either way, there is no need for `process.exit()`. If all tasks are done, gulp will terminate anyway.

Comment: The `gulp.dest()` isn't running.  The file isn't appearing in public/build.  When I pull out `process.exit()` it does though.

Comment: To be clear my comment was referring to your comment. "Didn't work when I wasn't returning g ": What didn't work? What exactly works now that you `return g;`?

Comment: Thanks for the help, fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

i hope to help, you do not need process.exit() because tasks gulp finish always if you use 'concat' your file should look this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
    concat = require('concat');

gulp.task('task', function() {
    gulp.src('js/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('newFile.js', {newLine: ';'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('js/build/'))
});
```

And finally write gulp task